# How to resolve newly appear action "California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA)"?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

A day before AdMob app shows the following warning

> The California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA) goes into effect January
>   12, December 2019. Learn how to manage your options for users in California.

How to make my Android app California Consumer Privacy Act compliance? or any **code** require for resolving the issue and **disappeared message**.

Thanks

Comment: restrict data processing or do not restrict data processing which one is best?

Comment: simple solution restrict data processing ... not effect your revue :)

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9561022 provides details of how to comply and code samples for IOS and Android on how to add a processing flag to comply with CCPA.